# JSON array issue

Tags: json

I am using the following data in JSON

```
{ "question":"abcd",
   "question":"xyz",
   "question":"wer",
            ...
            ...
}
```

I know that for an array square brackets can be used. But **here my first element itself** is an array. So is this valid ?-

```
{ ["question":"abcd",
   "question":"xyz",
   "question":"wer",
            ...
            ...
]}
```

Comment: No it's not. Check the specification: http://json.org/. But normally you don't have to worry about the correct format. Most popular languages provide ways to convert native data types/structures to JSON and back. There is hardly a reason to build JSON "manually".

Comment: Should this question be closed as too localized ? I feel that looking at the norm gives half the answer, the other half being very specific to OP's (unclear) structure modeling problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first element is an array this is what it should look like:

```
{
    "question" : ["abcd", "xyz", "wer"]
}
```

Comment: There is no name value pair inside the array. is that okay?

Comment: Yes, JSON allows you to specify arrays of primitives, strings, or (JSON) objects. In this case we've defined an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not. If you want a simple array of objects, each one having just a property called `question`, do it like this :

```
[{"question":"abcd"},
   {"question":"xyz"},
   {"question":"wer"},
            ...
            ...
]
```

But in JSON, a `{` introduces an object and must be followed by a property name :

[image]

Note that the whole standard, especially easy to read, is available at [JSON.org](http://json.org/)

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't, for multiple reasons. The first reason is if the root element is an object, then keys must be present. The second is exactly the inverse: in an array, there cannot possible be keys. It's not clear what you're trying to do, but for putting a dictionary into an array, you can use

```
[
    {
        "key": "value",
        "foo": "bar"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking exactly, did you want an object with property `question`, which is an array?

```
{
    "question": [
        "xyz", "abcd" ...
    ]
}
```